# How to Select and click the current image item in the slideshow of a repeater

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, repeater

Please, my senior code experts, I have a repeater that randomly display the images and text label from a folder using a jquery. I want to be able to select and click the current image such that it redirects to another page where the image details can be displayed. I will appreciate your help and contributions!

```
            <div id="banner-fade">

            <!-- start Basic Jquery Slider -->
            <ul class="bjqs">
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li>
                            <img src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Value") %>' title='<%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Text").ToString()).Split('.')[0].ToString() %>' alt=""></li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ul>
            <!-- end Basic jQuery Slider -->

        </div>
```

Below is the code behind...

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillPage();

    {

        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/pages/Management/Images/Products/"));
        List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {

            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

            files.Add(new ListItem(fileName, "/pages/Management/Images/Products/" + fileName));


        }
        Repeater1.DataSource = files;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Surround the `<img>` with a link.

```
<a href="www.linkToPageHere.com">
<img src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Value") %>' title='<%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Text").ToString()).Split('.')[0].ToString() %>' alt="">
</a>
```

Comment: I appreciate your gesture, but your posting is irrelevant to the question posted!

Comment: I disagree. This is a perfectly good answer. It is your question that may need refining. If you read this sentence `I want to be able to select and click the current image such that it redirects to another page where the image details can be displayed`. Adding a link will do just that.

Comment: VDWWD, I respect your comment and salute you. The reason I am uncomfortable with Brian's intelligent contribution is that we cannt point all the images to a single page using one href, since I am using a repeater that cycles through many images. I want to be able to reference each current image to a different page using the image id. I will appreciate your master solution.

Comment: Not sure if this will help much more, but you can still use the <a href="<%#Eval("Url")%>">